# what to do with a negative or r>curve.n/2 "r" in ecdsa signature

Tags: blockchain, signature, bitcoin, ecdsa

Hey guys it's your fellow beginner developer here again. Enough with chit chat!

Last time I asked you guys about signature and how to generate recoveryID for v of the signature and learnt new stuff.
Now while developing kind of a wallet again I got into trouble with signature and I need help.
A normal der signature would consist of two known parameters r and s, these two must be positive (BigInt, Uint8List, Hex) my signature has a normalize option where it fixes s to be positive and what actually happens is it checks if s is bigger than have of the curve order and reduces s from a value which I believe is curve order.

```
  var maxValueForS = BigInt.parse('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141', radix: 16);
  var treshHoldForS = BigInt.parse('7FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF5D576E7357A4501DDFE92F46681B20A0', radix: 16);
    if (BigInt.parse(sBytes.toHex(), radix: 16) > treshHoldForS) {
    sBytes = (maxValueForS - BigInt.parse(sBytes.toHex(), radix: 16)).toRadixString(16).toUint8List();
    }
```

where

```
maxValueForS is curve.order
treshHoldForS is curve.order/2
```

but when r is negative or should I say r>curve.order/2
the sign is not valid anymore and I can't do thing which are done to s already, it would ruin the sign and not get validate.
Any recommendations about r any ideas?
What should I do to get a valid r from the negative one.
One option is to regenerate a new signature when r is not positive.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like everything was fine but while trying to send signature in der format I had to add couple of zeroes before r while it was big enough so that some other languages would not interpret it as a negative value.